# Where can I find an online copy of Dietrich Kolde's "The Mirror of a Christian Man"?

Tags: resource-request, medieval-church, books, catechism

On the eve of the Reformation, *The Mirror of a Christian Man* (1470) by [Dietrich Kolde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietrich_Coelde) was one of the most popular Catholic catechism in the German language (German title: "Kerstenspiegel" or "Christenspiegel").  It is sometimes also titled as *A Fruitful Mirror of a Christian Man*.

[It has been argued](https://reformedreader.wordpress.com/2008/06/14/late-medieval-catechism-vs-the-heidelberg-catechism/) that the Protestant [Heidelberg Catechism](https://www.crcna.org/welcome/beliefs/confessions/heidelberg-catechism) was written partly as an antidote to the dismal attitude of the Christian faith at the time.  Is this true?  I would like to check this claim by myself.

This book is included in the 1982 book [Three Reformation Catechisms: Catholic, Anabaptist, Lutheran](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1933276.Three_Reformation_Catechisms), but I am looking for a freely downloadable copy of Kolde's book only, preferably in an English translation.